# Adding a hyperlink to every comment

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, hyperlink, comments

Here is an image of my comment format: http://oi40.tinypic.com/8w07jt.jpg

The hyperlink to each individual comment is the date and time with the url in the format of, for example: /nottingham/#comment-184

After going through my comment templates I found that these two functions do the following,

get_comments_link : Retrieves the link to the current post comments

AND

comments_link: Displays the link to the current post comments

The problem is I have no idea where to include these functions so it creates a hyperlink to every comment within every comment. Once this link has been created I'd also like to assign a div to it so I can format it to be in the bottom right corner of each comment.

My final goal is to manipulate the link so rather than the comment link itself it will automatically work in the facebook.com/sharer.php which I feel I can do myself once I figure out the previous part. Essentially it will be a share on facebook button, but I have found no plugins which do this yet and thought describing it as a hyperlink would be an easier way to explain what I'm trying to do.

Elsewhere I've been told the following: but not sure how to implement this...

> In functions.php I'd add a ['get_comments_link'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_comments_link) filter to return the desired link, including the  tag you need. Note that this is a filter, not a function. There is function with the same name, but it's part of WordPress itself. Use the filter to add a div to the existing link. Then style the new div to position it where you want it. I notice that the Photoria theme repositions the Reply link, which is coded at the bottom but displayed at the top. In the same way, your new  will be coded at the top but displayed at the bottom. Also see add_filter in the Codex. Add the new div to $link before returning it. The new div will need a class attribute so that you can work with it in CSS to make it look the way you want.

I hope I've made the question clear, please ask if I haven't. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally answered it myself, the code used to display the comment link was:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url ( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>"><img src=""</a>
```

Which was inserted in my comments template file within my comments body div which I then put into another div so I could format it itself to where I wanted it positioned.

Currently in the process of making the link automatically share through the facebook sharer...

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your comment template in your Wordpress theme.

Default is located in /comments.php

Some more informations could be found here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template

Comment: That's what I don't know to do though. I have tried editing my theme's comments.php but I'm unable to get any of the code within the loop (so it displays on all comments) just displays at the bottom after all the comments.

Just not sure how and where to edit so a change displays on all comments and whether it is as simple as adding get_comments_link and comments-link in a specific area of code.

I am a beginner to php!

Comment: you need to locate the template for 1 comment in your loop and post it in your question.

Comment: Sorry Zekth, don't quite get what you mean. I removed the comments function from my loop because I wanted the comments to display on all pages only, so put it in page.php instead. Do you mean this code or the code from comments.php (wp_list_comments) ?